# How to apply decltype to member function in declaration of operator[]

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

```
template <typename T>
class smart_ptr
{
public:
    // ... removed other member functions for simplicity
    T* get() { return ptr; }

    template <typename U>
    auto operator [](U u) const -> decltype((*get())[u])
    {
        return (*get())[u];
    }

    template <typename U>
    auto operator [](U u) -> decltype((*get())[u])
    {
        return (*get())[u];
    }

/*
    // These work fine:

    template <typename U>
    int operator [](U u)
    {
        return (*get())[u];
    }

    template <typename U>
    int& operator [](U u)
    {
        return (*get())[u];
    }
*/
private:
    T* ptr;
};

struct Test
{
};

struct Test2
{
    int& operator [](int i) { return m_Val; }
    int operator [](int i) const { return m_Val; }

    int m_Val;
};

int main()
{
    smart_ptr<Test> p1;
    smart_ptr<Test2> p2;
    p2[0] = 1;
}
```

Errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:55:9: error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'p2[0]'
```

ideone: http://ideone.com/VyjJ28

I'm trying to make smart_ptr's `operator []` work with the return type of `T::operator []` without explicitly specifying the `int` return type. However, as it is obvious from above, the compiler failed to compile the code. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me out.

Comment: This is not much of a question.

Comment: I thought it was obvious with the compiler errors and the full source code. Anyway, I added a paragraph to explain what I'm after.

Comment: For GCC 4.5.1, [this will do](http://ideone.com/CkOq0G) (used `std::declval<T>`). For newer versions (GCC 4.7+ specifically), you can use `*this->get()[u]` and a `const`-overload of `get` (as already shown in the link above).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you'd want better compiler errors. Here is what [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) has to say about this source (well, it says a lot more but this describes the problem):

```
decltype.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class smart_ptr<Test>’:
decltype.cpp:53:21:   required from here
decltype.cpp:9:51:error: cannot call member function ‘T* smart_ptr<T>::get() [with T = Test]’ without object
     auto operator [](U u) const -> decltype((*get())[u])       
                                                   ^
```

The fix to the problem is to call `get()` on an object, e.g.:

```
auto operator[](U u) const -> decltype((*this->get())[u])
```

(which also requires that there is a `const` member `get()`, of course).

Comment: This does not compile on GCC pre4.7 as Xeo has commented.

Comment: Actually, when I tried to compile the code with gcc, I noticed that I actually compiled it with gcc, although with a version from the SVN repository (gcc version 4.8.0 20121111). Clang happily compiles the original code.

Comment: Yeah like I said, GCC pre4.7 would fail.